# Excluding (All) from sets

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm using the following but i think there's probably a much simpler method of excluding the `All` members from the results?

```
WITH 
    SET [Non_All_Distributors] AS
        {FILTER(
            [Distributor Name].members,
            (InStr(1, [Distributor Name].CurrentMember.NAME, "All") = 0) 
            )}
    SET [Non_All_Countries] AS
        {FILTER(
            [Geography Country].members,
            (InStr(1, [Geography Country].CurrentMember.NAME, "All") = 0) 
            )}
SELECT  
    NON EMPTY 
        [Dimension].[Hierarchy].DEFAULTMEMBER 
    ON COLUMNS, 

    NON EMPTY 
        [Non_All_Distributors]
        *
        [Non_All_Countries]
        *
        Tail([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day].Members,60)  
        *  
        { 
        [Measures].[Revenue], 
        [Measures].[NumClients]
        } 
    ON ROWS 

FROM [OURCUBE]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use

```
SELECT  
    NON EMPTY 
        [Dimension].[Hierarchy].DEFAULTMEMBER 
    ON COLUMNS, 

    NON EMPTY 
        [dimension of Distributor Name].[Distributor Name].[Distributor Name].Members
        *
        [dimension of Geography Country].[Geography Country].[Geography Country].Members
        *
        Tail([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day].Members,60)  
        *  
        { 
        [Measures].[Revenue], 
        [Measures].[NumClients]
        } 
    ON ROWS 

FROM [OURCUBE]
```

There is no need to define sets here. you can directly state the distributor and country members in the rows clause.

By repeating the attribute name, you restrict the attribute hierarchy - which you refer to by `[dim].[attrib name]` to the level below the `All` member, which happens to have the same name as the attribute again. An attribute hierarchy has two levels: level 0 contains the 'All' member and level 1 all the members of the attribute. (This is true only if you did not do special configurations like setting the attribute as non aggregateabable, but I assume the standard case, as you have `All` members in your hierarchies.

Apart from being more simple, this statement will run much faster, as `Filter` is a real performance killer in many cases.

Comment: +1 - wonderful stuff Frank ....I don't need the dimension name simply using the following is doing it for me `[Distributor Name].[Distributor Name]` - I don't design the cubes. On e question - because I'm able to just use `[Distributor Name].[Distributor Name]` does this mean that `[Distributor Name]` is a dimension?!

Comment: @whytheq No, I would not assume that `[Distributor Name]` is the dimension. Analysis Services just tries to be clever and guess from partial names what the user presumably meant. This may be correct in many cases, but sometimes wrong or can cause malfunctioning in case the cube evolves in future, and there is another dimension with an attribute with the same name, and possibly on huge cubes may take a little time to find potential elements matching a name. Hence I tend to write the complete names, even if these can be quite long.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [Descendants](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Descendants.html) function and the AFTER option as following; this way you get all the members of the hierarchy below the all member:

```
  select 
     [Measures].[Amount] on 0,  
     Descendants([Customers].[Geography].[All], 1, AFTER ) on 1

  from [Sales]
```

(edited: with a request working with MSAS Adv. Works : removed the distance param)

```
select
 Measures].[Order Count] on 0,
 Descendants( [Geography].[Geography].[All], , AFTER ) on 1

from [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: +1 although can't seem to get this to work - if I use this `Descendants([Operator].[Operator].[Distributor Name].[All], 1, AFTER )` then the query runs with no reported errors but no data is returned. `[Operator].[Operator].[Distributor Name]` is the full path i.e. [dimension].[hierarchy].[level]. Its level 2.

Comment: I've edited the response; be sure to select properly the [All] member in a separate select without any descendant and the like : [dim].[hierarchy].[all] should select it : 'all' has a special meaning in MDX.